# Objects mapping to tables

Tags: sql, oop

For a program with an OO front-end and a SQL back-end, can one have each parent class map to its own table and each child class map to it's own table, then use joins in queries to allow returning all the child class's attributes?  If so, is it advisable?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150362/oo-and-sql

Comment: ChrisW, that was my question you linked to.  I had to leave my response to your last comment as an answer to the question because apparently I lost the cookie the site used to recognize me as the asker of that question.  <p>Anyway, this question follows up on the example of object and table mapping you posted in that other thread.  <p>Specifically, I wanted to see if it's ok to have a parent class mapped to one table and each child class mapped to their own tables, then do a join to return all of an object's attributes (some are contained in parent class table and some in subclass table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible and reasonably widespread. It also works well when you have minimal sub-classing, and the business logic maps easily to the objects being used. However, with only a little extensability in the mapping layer, you can easily create objects that are combinations of several tables, perhaps even doing sub-classes. (I've written such layers and take care to make such hooks possible.)

It is advisable to always use a data mapping layer because you do not want excessive SQL littering your code. OTOH, if your class structure is more heirarchical rather than relational, you might look at an OO database (I hear PostGreSQL can do that) and a suitable mapping layer.

Comment: Thanks to all but this answer seems like the most complete.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do that with an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool like [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx).  As to whether it's advisable, that's a religious question -- I try not to answer those. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Object-Relational Mapping frameworks suchas NHibernate and Hibernate take care of these things for you.